# setting document root in antoher partition on ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

i would like to place my apache document root inside another partition of my ubuntu hard drive, but i keep getting `forbidden` message, when i place to my home directory it woking find, how could that be? is the group or owner affected ? here mysite.conf  and apache2.conf when i place my document root in my home folder (Working)

```
#site-available/mysite.conf
DocumentRoot /home/jono/www

#/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /home/jono/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

bu when i change document root to another partition i keep getting `forbidden` messasge

```
#site-available/mysite.conf
DocumentRoot /media/jono/website_data/www

#/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /media/jono/website_data/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

is the owner/group access affected ? or there is another problem ?

Comment: did you grant apache access to all of those directories and files? that doesn't  magically happen because you set `Directory` in apache...

Comment: how do i do that ? chmod / chgrp ? would yo like give me some example please?

Comment: yes, chmod and/or chgrp, depending on exactly what you want those permissions to be.

Comment: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/jono/website_data/www && sudo adduser jonopc www-data`  I'm using this command but still no luck

Comment: you need to grant access to ALL of the directories. you're starting at `www` and going downards. but apache needs access to `media`, `jono`, etc.. as well. e.g. you're putting a "free, take one" display inside a locked bank vault.

Comment: hi March please post some answer regarding this problem, it's working now, i can accept your answer after all, thanks dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at last it's working, i have to grant all access to `www:data` for accesing whole directory thanks to you @mark-b, using `chown -R www-data:www-data` to whole directory isn't good idea but for local development is ok i guest

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround (safe and quick) you can make the mounting point of your external hard driver to the default root directory ( /var/www by default).

Assigning the mounting point to a per-existing directory is safe but the old content can't be reached unless you unmounted the driver.

To learn more how to create a mounting point refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically). To know more about assigning the mounting point to a per-existing directory refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11269/are-pre-existing-files-in-a-mountpoint-directory-safe-and-uneffected).