# 403 error on XAMPP change document root

Tags: apache, xampp, http-status-code-403

I have installed XAMPP on Linux Mint. Got it running OK, then I wanted to change the htdocs folder location to another partition.

I made these changes to httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/media/alex/776FAD4B34B3CF0A/XAMPP htdocs"
<Directory "/media/alex/776FAD4B34B3CF0A/XAMPP htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and also did:

```
cd /media/alex/776FAD4B34B3CF0A
sudo chmod -R 777 "XAMPP htdocs"
```

but I keep getting a 403 error, despite restarting Apache.

Any suggestions please!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596331/setting-document-root-in-antoher-partition-on-ubuntu) looks pretty much exactly like your problem, doesn't it? :)

What's probably missing is this (assumung that your Apache is running under www-data):

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/alex/776FAD4B34B3CF0A
sudo chmod -R g+rw /media/alex/776FAD4B34B3CF0A
```

Eventually that won't be enough though and you gotta go with

```
chown -R www-data:www-data
```

But that's more like your last resort...